# How can I SELECT a query by incrementing days?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I generate an Excel using an SQL query per each day:

```
SELECT      COUNT(res_id) as TotalReservation
FROM        bup_vw_res_reservation
WHERE       res_deleted = 0 
AND         DATEPART(DAY,res_date_start) = 1
```

I execute this Query each time I want to change the DAY. To generate 1 sheet in my Excel file, I need to open and close 30 connections in my page. And if I need to make another sheet for a different company ,then I need to execute the same 30 query again. And the page becomes extremely slow :(

Is there another way to get the same result in 1 query ?

Comment: so you're saying that you have to change the number in the last line from `1` to `2` and `3` (and so on)? And you want to get the results for all those numbers in one query?

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to do that. That's why I execute this query so many times and it makes my webpage inefficient and slow... :(

Comment: In that case, Dervall's answer is correct: `between 1 and 30` or `31` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the total, you could do

```
DATEPART(DAY, res_date_start) BETWEEN 1 AND 30
```

If you need each reservation count for each day, do this

```
SELECT      COUNT(res_id) as TotalReservation, DATEPART(DAY,res_date_start)
FROM        bup_vw_res_reservation
WHERE       res_deleted = 0 
GROUP BY    DATEPART(DAY,res_date_start)
```

Comment: GROUP BY skips the empty results, How can I see the NULL results as well? (Something like LEFT OUTER JOIN)

Comment: That is harder to do, since that would require the SQL to GROUP BY something that isn't part of the query, like a day number that doesn't exist in your SQL. There are solutions, but you would need to first create some sort of temporary table that contains all the interesting days, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it with your reserversions and apply the same grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, group the results by DATEPART(DAY,res_date_start) as so:

```
SELECT      COUNT(res_id) as TotalReservation, DATEPART(DAY,res_date_start) 
FROM        bup_vw_res_reservation
WHERE       res_deleted = 0 
            and res_date_start between beginning_of_month and end_of_month
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY,res_date_start)
```

Now you have all the results you need and you can iterate through them to generate the Excel spreadsheet per row.